# Using APPLICATION.QUIT in MS-Word VBA but Application Immediately Re-opens

Tags: vba, ms-word, close-application

**Desired Behavior**:
When the below code completes, MS Word is supposed to close and remain closed.

**Problem**:
The problem is that the MS Word application re-starts and opens "Instructions.docx," which has the macro-button that points to the below VBA Sub in Module1 of Normal.dotm.

**FYIs**:
(1) My first time posting.
(2) This problem was not happening about six months, before I took some Windows 10 & Office 365 updates.
(3) MS Word for Office 365 MSO (16.0.12527.20260) 32-bit.
(4) Windows 10 Pro, 64-bit OS, i5-6500 @ 2.5 GHz, 8 GB RAM.

**Question**:
How do I get the MS Word application to stay closed when my Normal.dotm VBA closes it?

```
Sub Finishing()
'To reset and save Instruction.docx
'To move existing Outputs folder to a new date-specific destination
'To close all open *.docx's then quit MS Word application
    Dim TodaysYear, FridaysDate, ToPath, FromPath As String
'(1) Reset_All_Checkboxes as adapted from Greg Maxey
    Dim oCC As ContentControl
        For Each oCC In ActiveDocument.Range.ContentControls
        oCC.Checked = False
    Next
'(2) Move_and_Rename_Outputs_Dir as adapted from Ron de Bruin
    ToPath = "C:\Users\me\OneDrive\Documents\Trade Records\" & Format(Date, "yyyy") & "\" & Format(DateAdd("d", 4, Date), "yyyy-mm-dd") 'add 4 days
    FromPath = "C:\Users\me\OneDrive\Documents\Outputs"
    Dim FSO As Object
    Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    FSO.MoveFolder Source:=FromPath, Destination:=ToPath
'(3) Save and close all open files then quit Word
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        'Loop through open documents
        Do Until .Documents.Count = 0
            .Documents(1).Close SaveChanges:=wdSaveChanges
        Loop
        .Quit SaveChanges:=wdSaveChanges 'Quit MS Word
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Your resetting of content controls implies you're modifying an existing document instead of using a template. If you used a template, that wouldn't be necessary. If you saved the modified document to the output folder, you wouldn't need to move it afterwards. In any event, you can't move an open Word document to another folder. Regardless, there have been numerous reports lately of a Windows update bug that causes Word to open spontaneously. Your problem may be related to that.

Comment: I'll comment back to you point by point:
1.) modifying an existing document -- yes, this is what I am doing. Document is Instructions.docx.
2.) you saved the modified document to the output folder -- not quite. There are only excel documents in the folder named "outputs." Instructions.docx always resides and never moves from a directory called "static inputs."
3.) you can't move an open Word document to another folder -- good to know; not what I'm trying to do.

Do you want me to describe the process flow better?

Comment: 4.) bug that causes Word to open spontaneously -- Good tip, I'll make sure I'm patched ASAP; my MS Word has never started without a user prompt, except at the end of the macro in question, and then it spawns very reproducibly. Is there something I could monitor, e.g. in Services or with Process Explorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by amending section 3 to the following:

```
'(3) Save Instructions.docx without prompts then prompt to close all open files then quit Word
    'This achieves Desired Behavior: Instructions.docs exit-macro runs without problem of re-opening MS Word application after the Word macro closes the Instructions document & exits the Word application
    Documents("Instructions .docx").Activate
    ActiveDocument.Save 'if Instructions.docx is the only open Word doc, macro completes without prompt
    Application.Quit SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges 'This saves option is for changes to Normal.dotm. Other Save Options are wdSaveChanges & wdPromptToSaveChanges.
```